# How can i Auto Size the Column width in RDLC Report

Tags: c#, windows

I have created Windows application with RDLC Report. I am binding(Generating) dynamic columns and data's in RDLC Report Using Matrix control, I need to make Auto size of Column width for each Column in Matrix of RDLC report. So Can any one suggest me to make the Auto Size of Column Width in RDLC.

Thanks in Advance.
Mohan G

Answer (score -1):

In reporting, the column width and height is hard coded, hence we cannot set the column width or height dynamically or based on a given function see in the link http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0c7d35c4-a21b-4ca1-a7cc-b20839ef31f8/how-can-i-auto-size-the-column-width-in-rdlc-report

Comment: Hi mike, Thanks for your Reply. I will try what you suggested above.